# HtmlAgilityPack getting all value inside a <div>

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get values from a website. The values are inside a div, where's more div under that "main div" (if I can call it like this).
What I want to, is to get those divs value thats inside the "main div".
I tried with this code:

```
 string url = "www.examplesite.com";

    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
    HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='plex_container']");
    foreach (HtmlNode node in collection)
    {
        string cptitle = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='pltexts']").InnerText;
        listBox1.Items.Add(cptitle);
    }
```

The website's structure (while in F12 running-time) looks like this:

```
    <body onload="initialize()" id="dashboard">
<div id="header">...</div>
     <div id="dashboard_container">
         <div id="comm" class="comm_expanded">
            <div id="pl_header_tab">...</div>
            <div id="pltext_tab">...</div>
            <div id="plex_container">
                <div id="pl_status"></div>
                <div id="pltexts">
                   <div class="plext">...</div> // <-- Im trying to get these values
                   <div class="plext">...</div> // <-- 
                   <div class="plext">...</div> // <-- 
                   <div class="plext">...</div> // <--
                   <div class="plext">...</div> // <--
```

I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error for the foreach...

Comment: Your html doesnt contain a divs with id=`plext_container` and it's also `pltexts` not `plexts`

Comment: Sorry, I mispelled it. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Using the provided HTML snippet, you can use a XPath selector to get the text nodes directly:

```
var html =
@"
<body onload='initialize()' id='dashboard'>
<div id='header'>...</div>
<div id='dashboard_container'>
<div id='comm' class='comm_expanded'>
<div id='pl_header_tab'>...</div>
<div id='pltext_tab'>...</div>
<div id='plex_container'>
<div id='pl_status'></div>
<div id='pltexts'>
<div class='plext'>00</div>
<div class='plext'>01</div>
<div class='plext'>02</div>
<div class='plext'>03</div>
<div class='plext'>04</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>";
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
var textNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    "//div[@id='pltexts']/div[@class='plext']/text()"
);
if (textNodes != null)
{
    foreach (var t in textNodes) Console.WriteLine(t.InnerText);
}
```

Output:

```
00
01
02
03
04
```

Comment: This could be good, but I want to load it from the website provided, not just from a variable, because I need those datas from the website.

Comment: @MassKos - uuuuhhhh....you can **easily** do that by **replacing** the `html` variable above and `HtmlDocument` initilization with your code. `HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(....`

Comment: I cannot get this thing to work...With your code, it doesn't gives me any texts, and nothing. Is it possible this happens because of the site where I want to get texts from requires Google login? (I did login through VisualStudio, and webbrowser)

Comment: @MassKos, Please share url of this website. In my experience Agility has trouble parsing syntactically incorrect HTML. A workaround is changing settings for the library to ignore parsing error or running an external tool for correcting HTML.